# Colon being sanitized from variable Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce Follow Ups and have created a custom variable for it to use using the following code in functions.php

```
add_action( 'fue_before_variable_replacements', 'fue_register_web_variable_replacements', 10, 4);

function fue_register_web_variable_replacements( $var, $email_data, 
$fue_email, $queue_item ) { 
$variables = array(
    'webinar_url'   => ''
);

if ( isset( $email_data['test'] ) && $email_data['test'] ) {
    $variables['webinar_url'] = 'http://example.com';

    if ( !empty( $email_data['order_id'] ) ) {
        $webinar_url = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'webinar_link', true );

        if ( !empty( $webinar_url ) ) {
            $variables['webinar_url'] = $webinar_url;
        }
    }
} else {
    if ( !empty( $queue_item->order_id ) ) {
        $webinar_url = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'webinar_link', true );

        if ( !empty( $webinar_url ) ) {
            $variables['webinar_url'] = $webinar_url;
        }
    }
}


$var->register( $variables );
}
```

This allows me to use the short code {webinar_url} in the Follow Up Email creator. My issue is that when I add this to just output it's value it displays http://example.com properly.

But if I use this as the value for the href for the a element

```
<a href="{webinar_url}">Join the Webinar</a>
```

it outputs the value as http//example.com. It has removed the : from the output.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Thank you.

Comment: What if to output like that: <a href="<?php echo webinar_url; ?>">Join the Webinar</a>

Comment: seems serialization is the prob here while saving... so use a json_encoded value of your url and while printing decode it

Comment: The issue is that to use this shortcode, I'm simply placing {webinar_url} into the regular Wordpress Editor space. How would I stop serialization from happening?